# I need to select only one occurrence of dash in my table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Im facing this problem: I need to select columns with only one occurence of dash in table like this:

```
Id   Name
1    Boots - black
2    Sneakers - Logan - white
3    Shirt - white
4    Pants - cargo - blue
5    Hat – green
```

So it will type out only column 1,3 and 5 - because they have only one dash and others have 2 or more.

Ive tried this query: Select * from products where Name like “%-%“; ,but it selected all  occurences of dash, no matter if theres one or more.

 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LENGTH and REPLACE:

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE (LENGTH(Name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Name, '-', ''))) = 1
```

If there is only one "dash" in the `Name`, the calculation of `LENGTH(Name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Name, '-', ''))` will return one.